# Getting a value based on the latest date for another given value

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to lookup the latest amount for a particular tenant.  E.g.

[image]

The formulae in B2 should return £20.00

The source data is not sorted.  There will only be only 1 payment per day for a tenant.  I am using the latest version of Excel.

Comment: What have you tried? and what have the results been?  Will the dates for each tenant always be sorted ascending?  Or might they be random? Can there be more than one payment on the same date? What version of Excel?

Comment: Hi Ron.  I have tried VLOOKUP.  The only way I think that would work is if I changed the source data to add a composite column and I wanted to find a neater solution before doing that.  I have also played around with INDEX and MATCH.  The way I have seen this done is by changing the lookups into a boolean comparison, I can see how this would work with one criteria, but not with two (latest date AND tenant name).

Comment: Hi Ron, I have answered your questions in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it:

[image]

The formulae in F2 (Latest Amount) is :

{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(E2=B:B)*(MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,E2)=A:A),0))}

(Its an array formulae, entered with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER)

Thanks to https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 0):

@MikeFleming's approach should work well.

Another approach, using some of the new Functions available in Excel (`SORT` and `FILTER` in this case).  I am also using a **Table** with structured references. `tenantName` can be any cell, or a named reference to a cell.

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(pmtTbl,pmtTbl[Tenant]=tenantName),1,1,FALSE),0,3))
```

or (a bit shorter using defaults for certain arguments):

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,INDEX(FILTER(SORT(pmtTbl),pmtTbl[Tenant]=tenantName),0,3))
```

- `FILTER`: return only the rows in the table containing `tenantName`
- `SORT`: Sort by the date column, ascending
- `INDEX`: Return only the Amount column of the table
- `LOOKUP`: This is the method to return the last entry in that column.

[image]